# Optional validation, if present, must be 8 integers

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form field that is optional, but if someone enters data, they have to enter 8 integers only.

What kind of model annotation should I use for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute.aspx) attribute, which work properly with nullable types. Specify upper and lower range for your number. Note that if [Required](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.aspx) is absent - this field is optional.

```
[Range(10000000, 99999999, ErrorMessage = "Number must be exactly 8 digit long")]
public int? Field {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the regular expression attribute with the following regex:

```
[RegularExpression(@"\d{8}?")]
```

This means 8 digits, but it's optional

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex expression: `^\d{8}?$`

It allows input only 8 digits or nothing.